# Power BI: transform JSON Records into columns by Record row index

Tags: mysql, sql, json, powerbi

This is my first day using Power BI so go easy on me!

Within my table I have a column of JSON records

[Column of JSON records]

[image: 1]

Each Record has 3 rows, with 2 columns (I only need the value of the first column).

[Record with 3 rows]

[image: 2]

As the index/position of each record's rows represents the same thing, I want to convert the index/position into a new column in the table, and populate it with each records' corresponding value from column 1.

For example:

The JSON Record from table row 1:

```
----
1479
1481
1486
---
```

The JSON Record from table row 2:

```
----
1351
1536
1356
---
```

Expected output:

```
New Column 1 | New Column 2 
1479         | 1351         
1481         | 1536         
1486         | 1356
```

I have searched for a solution but to no avail. Hopefully someone can help me here. Let me know if you need any further clarification.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to achieve this by using a couple of Transform functions. I reversed parsing the column to JSON, and instead used the `Split Column` function to separate the JSON by the `,` delimiter (creating the 3 columns I required), and then isolated the required data within the columns using the `Extract` function.